# Clone specific branch

Tags: git

I am working with a team of programmers on a project. I would like to clone/pull a specific branch from the remote repository (called **Marshmallow**) and the name of the branch is called `john/dev/operations`. How could I clone that branch on my local repository?

Thanks in advance!

I would like the branch could be displayed in here :

```
└────╼ git branch
  dev/jay/cancel-deposit
  dev/jay/customize_emailtemplates
  dev/jay/perceptions
  dev/jay/test
* master
```

Comment: Try this: **git clone -b john/dev/operations --single-branch <remote-repo-url>**

Comment: @sajibkhan This clone the whole repository. I just want to integrate the new branch to all my other branches.

Comment: If you already have the repository, "clone" is the wrong word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fetch the repository.

```
$ git fetch origin    # assume remote name is origin
```

Then checkout the branch.

```
$ git checkout john/dev/operations  # create a new local branch with the history of remote same named branch 

$ git branch
```

Comment: Now you understand ;)